# codeigniter query issue

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have this query:

```
$this->db->select('COUNT(tran_ID) AS count, CASE WHEN MONTH(days)>=4 THEN concat(YEAR(days), "-", YEAR(days)+1) ELSE concat(YEAR(days)-1, "-", YEAR(days)) END AS format_date,product_class AS saleCol');
```

I get syntax error on

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHEN MONTH(days)>=4 THEN concat(YEAR(days), `"-"`, YEAR(days)+1) ELSE concat(YEA' at line 1

SELECT COUNT(tran_ID) AS count, `CASE` WHEN MONTH(days)>=4 THEN concat(YEAR(days), `"-"`, YEAR(days)+1) ELSE concat(YEAR(days)-1, `"-"`, YEAR(days)) END AS format_date, `product_class` AS saleCol FROM (`transactions`) WHERE `trans_type` = 'E' AND `product_class` != '0' GROUP BY `format_date`, `product_class`
```

Comment: If you're going to run an advanced query as this, you may aswell run the entire thing through `query()`. Active Records are good for simplier approaches, but regardless, `query()` allows you to do exactly as you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query, added `FALSE` as the second parameter in select statement

```
$this->db->select(
                  'COUNT(tran_ID) AS count, 
                   CASE WHEN MONTH(days)>=4 THEN concat(YEAR(days), "-", YEAR(days)+1)
                     ELSE concat(YEAR(days)-1, "-", YEAR(days)) 
                   END AS format_date,
                   product_class AS saleCol',FALSE);
```

Comment: I had faced the same issue for complex query. Happy to hear that it's fixed your issue.